# Creating specific view for specific retrieval of data in chouchbase

Tags: c#, linq, couchbase, nosql

One of my teammates and I had a conversation about creating views in couchbase for retrieving data.

So my suggestion was to create views for specific retrieval of data this way it would be much faster and straight forward. For instance, we have two different admin:

- **admin for specific group**
- **super admin**

Admin retrieve data from their specific group and super admin gets data from all of the groups.

It would make sense to just limit admin for group to get those data that belongs to them rather than get all data then process them in the back-end and compare which ones are belong to a group.

**For instance:**
Create couchbase view that accept group id and query all of its data

On the other hand, she only create views if there are complicated stuff like computation and creating more views might be hard to maintain.

Because currently we only use one view that gets all of the data and once we have them we process them by getting specific data for the a particular group in the back-end using LINQ.

**Document Structure:**

```
{
   "fooReference": "",
   "groupId": 8,
   "fooName": "projectTest",
   "externalId": "PR572",
   "fooDescription": "OG QGpCst vXAuu",
   "property5": {
       "property1": "124",
       "code": "US",
       "value": 267206,
       "start": "2014-10-01T00:00:00Z",
       "end": "2017-09-30T00:00:00Z"
   },
   "property6": [
       "string1",
       "string2",
       "string14"
   ],
   "property7": [
   ],
   "property8": [
   ],
   "dateAdded": "2016-02-11T07:22:15.2483042Z",
   "ownerId": 72,
   "dateUpdated": "2016-02-11T07:22:15.2483042Z",
   "property9": [
       {
           "id": 72,
           "type": 0
       }
   ],
   "property10": false,
   "id": "345",
   "deleted": false,
   "type": "Foo",
   "subtype": "Foo"
}
```

**Get All Query:**

```
function (doc, meta) {
  if (doc.type == "Foo" && !doc.deleted) {
    emit(meta.id, null); 
  }
}
```

**This is the sample query I want to suggest:**
If I want it to get by groupId, just pass the groupId in the `emit`

```
function(doc, meta) {
     if (doc.type == "Foo" && !doc.deleted) {
         emit(doc.groupId, doc);
     }
 }
```

If I want to get `externalId` I just have to pass the `externalId` to the `emit`

```
function(doc, meta) {
         if (doc.type == "Foo" && !doc.deleted) {
             emit(doc.externalId, doc);
         }
     }
```

This way we have different queries with different roles of getting documents, and we don't have to just get all of the document by its `id` and process them in the back-end using LINQ.

Example in process them in the backend:

**Getting the groupId:**

```
var foos = _fooRepository.GetAll();
foos = foos.Where(s => s.GroupId == group.Id).ToList();
```

**Getting the externalId:**

```
var foos = _fooRepository.GetAll();
foos = foos.Where(s => s.externalId == foo.externalId).ToList();
```

**Note:** Somehow performance is somewhat important to us specially when rendering pages that retrieve data for the users.

So my question is what is the best approach to this kind of scenario?

Comment: To give an answer, we would need to know the structure of your documents and the queries you want to ask. In general, a view both defines an index by which certain documents can be efficiently retrieved, and the classical database view, namely a selection and projection of documents. If your queries differ by just the start and end key values (say staff of just one group or staff of all groups), you can do with one view. If the queries are structurally different (say staff of a group or staff by academic degree), you'll need more.

Comment: @TAM I updated my question. can't provide much of document structure but that's what it looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested your proposal on a live system, but using a view for each of your query types looks like the textbook solution for the requirements you have. If you need queries to access your data via different criteria, define a view for each set of criteria.

Performance considerations:

Space: Your views will each generate an index containing, for each selected document, the emitted value and the document id. This should be no problem at all compared with your overall data volume. The only exception for this that I can image would be extremely limited hardware resources, e.g. if your app runs on an embedded hardware in a car where each cent counts.

Runtime: The total sum of operations on your database depends on the number of inserts and updates that change your index plus the number of queries on your data together with the count of records retrieved by each query. Now, if the count of relevant insert/update operations would exceed the count of queries, the index might increase the total count of operations. In most database applications, however, there are much more queries than modifying operations, so each operation to keep your index up-to-date will be more than compensated by the reduced effort to select the data you need. If still in doubt, you might make a rough estimation of the count of insert, update, and query operations pertaining your views.

From another perspective, if you have the requirement to select data according to some criteria, there are two ways to achieve this: In the database, using a view, or in your application. Doing it in your application comes with two performance issues: More data have to be transferred from your database to your application, and your application will need to include a selection algorithm that, most probably, won't be faster than the one provided by the database.

To sum up, unless your insert/update operations dramatically exceed your queries, defining views for your different ways to access your data are the way to go.